# Average value of $g'$ on $[a, b]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $g$ is a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and if $g'$ is also continuous on $[a, b]$. How do I find the average value of $g'$ on $[a, b]$?

I know that if a function is continuous on $[a, b]$, then the average value is
$$g_{avg}(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\ dx$$

I'm a little stuck at this point. Some tips and/or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$ g'$ is continuous at $ [a,b] $, and is then integrable at $ [a,b]$.

By FTC, we have

$$\int_a^bg'(x)dx=\Bigl[g(x)\Bigr]_a^b=g(b)-g(a)$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot :)